# Android record audio as mono doesn't work

Tags: android, audio, media

I want to record mono audio. I'm setting the `AudioRecord` param to be `ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`, but when I analyze the resulting file with Audacity, I see that it was actually recorded as stereo.

Relevant code:

```
bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(AudioFileFunc.AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

audioRecord = new AudioRecord(AudioFileFunc.AUDIO_INPUT, AudioFileFunc.AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSizeInBytes);
```

What's problem? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Are you getting two channels of the same mono waveform? Are you using `CHANNEL_IN_MONO` in your WavWriter when actually writing the file to the SD? Which device are you testing on? (different devices have been known provide different results...)

Comment: Yes, I tested app on Sumsung.